# Using Simple HTML DOM to Scrape?

Tags: php, dom, loops, simple-html-dom, scrape

Simple HTML DOM is basically a php you add to your pages which lets you have simple web scraping. It's good for the most part but I can't figure out the manual as I'm not much of a coder. Are there any sites/guides out there that have any easier help for this? (the one at php.net is a bit too complicated for me at the moment) Is there a better place to ask this kind of question?

The site for it is at: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

I can scrape stuff that has specific classes like `<tr class="group">`, but not for stuff that's in between. For example.. This is what I currently use...

```
$url = 'http://www.test.com';
$html = file_get_html($url);
foreach($html->find('tr[class=group]') as $result)
  {
    $first = $result->find('td[class=category1]',0);
    $second = $result->find('td[class=category2]',0);
    echo $first.$second;
  }
}
```

But here is the kind of code I'm trying to scrape.

```
<table>
  <tr class="Group">
    <td>
      <dl class="Summary">
        <dt>Heading 1</dt>
          <dd><a href="#123" class="ViewProfile">Cat</a></dd>
          <dd><a href="#032" class="ViewProfile">Bacon</a></dd>
        <dt>Heading 2</dt>
          <dd><a href="#143" class="ViewProfile">Narwhal</a></dd>
          <dd><a href="#642" class="ViewProfile">Ice Soap</a></dd>
      </dl>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I'm trying to extract the content of each `<dt>` and put it to a variable. Then I'm trying to extract the content of each `<dd>` and put it to a variable, but nothing I tried works. Here's the best I could find, but it gives me back only the first heading repeatedly rather than going to the second.

```
foreach($html->find('tr[class=Summary]') as $result2)
  {
    echo $result2->find('dt',0)->innertext;
  }
```

Thanks to anyone who can help. Sorry if this is not clear or that it's so long. Ideally I'd like to be able to understand these DOM commands more as I'd like to figure this out myself rather than someone here just do it (but I'd appreciate either).

**TL;DR:** I am trying to understand how to use the commands listed in the manual (url above). The 'manual' isn't easy enough. How do you go about learning this stuff?

Comment: I pretty much hate Simple DOM. The hellish mixture of objects and arrays you get back is... hellish. PHPQuery is kind of cool, but ultimately I moved to Python and Beautiful Soup for this type of task.

Comment: Yeah, ideally I'd rather use Python, but then I'd have to learn something that ends up being more work for me. I've had a look at PHPQuery and can't make head nor tails of it. I just wish there was an easy way to learn these things... or even if there was a book or something that I could work through.

Comment: Just my suggestion, because I had the same problem learning and concluded that the 'Simple DOM' is anything but. I consider it to be truly awful, and wholeheartedly recommend seeking any other alternative possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `$result2->find('dt',0)` gives you back element `0`, which is the first. If you omit that, you should be able to get an array <strike>(or nodelist)</strike> instead. Something like this:

```
foreach($html->find('tr[class=Summary]') as $result2)
{
    foreach ($result2->find('dt') as $node)
    {
       echo $node->innertext;
    }
}
```

You don't strictly need the outer for loop, since there's only 1 tr in your document. You could even leave it altogether to find each `dt` in the document, but for tools like this, I think it's a good thing to be both flexible and strict, so you are prepared for multiple rows, but don't accidentally parse `dt`s from anywhere in the document.

Comment: Wow thanks! It stopped repeating. Sorry for the complicated question and thanks for your help. Theres actually a ton of 'tr' tags in the document, but I cut most out for simplicity. The outer tag just cuts it down to what I'm showing in this example.